# Text in <div> different in Firefox

Tags: firefox, text

Does anyone know of any fixes/workarounds for Firefox (3 and 4) handling text slightly differently than other browsers, specifically:

- Character-spacing (Firefox sometimes slightly wider with positive character-spacing defined in px)
- Non-splitting of hyphenated words (in, say, Safari, if "co-operate" appears at the end of a line it may be split into "co-" and "operate" ... but in Firefox it is not, and the whole word appears on a new line).

Not sure whether the two are related. Any tips? Thanks in advance.

Comment: that is browser behaviour, text cannot be the same in every browser on every platfrom. http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use reset stylesheets (for example [Eric Meyer's reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/))

And for 2nd , you can check CSS's [word-wrap attr](http://www.css3.com/css-word-wrap/).

Thereby, you can reset everything for every browser and set again as you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override the default browser setting for word-spacing, you can use the following in your main CSS file:

```
* { word-spacing:0px; }
```

Just note that not all browser support the wildcard. If you don't want to use a wildcard, you can use just a normal select:

```
div { word-spacing:0px; }
```

[Word-spacing on W3Schools](http://w3schools.com/css/pr_text_word-spacing.asp) contains more information on word-spacing.

About your second problem, I am not getting the same symptom as you are. In Firefox 3.6.13 any word with a hyphen in it at the end of the line is breaking up in my computer.

Doesn't matter what the Word-wrap value is, Firefox in my computer will break the word up if necessary.